# Pandas Excel row extract changes fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I work on a small translation program. I have a .xlsx file attached with 5 columns each in different Language(English, French, German, Spanish, Italian).

The program provides a drop down list with with each row from the .xlsx being one of the available options(English Only). Selecting one of the options takes the English Value and adds it to a list.

I then use following to later extract the whole row of other languages based on the English selected and split by deliminator(;):

```
instructionList = ['Avoid contact with light-coloured fabrics, leather and upholstery. Colour may transfer due to the nature of indigo-dyed denim.']

for i in range(len(instructionList)):
            newCompInst.append(translationFile.loc[translationFile['English'] == instructionList[i]].to_string(index=False, header=False))
            newInst = [i.replace('  ', ',;') for i in newInst ]
        strippedInst = [item.lstrip() for item in newInst ]
print('strippedInst: ', strippedInst)
```

The output I get from the following code is:

```
strippedInst:  ['Avoid contact with light-coloured fabrics, lea...,;Bviter le contact avec les tissus clairs, le c...,;Kontakt mit hellen Stoffen, Leder und Polsterm...,;Evitar el contacto con tejidos de colores clar...,;Evitare il contatto con capi dai colori delica...']
```

After running this code all of the languages get cut in half and the rest of the sentence gets replaced with '...' - (NOTE the ENGLISH in the 'strippedInst' and compare with what has been inputed to the loop (instructionList).

The output gets cut only when the sentence is long. I tried running smaller phrases and it all seems to come through fine.

This is the Expected output:

```
strippedInst: 
['
Avoid contact with light-coloured fabrics, leather and upholstery. Colour may transfer due to the nature of indigo-dyed denim.,;
Éviter le contact avec les tissus clairs, le cuir et les tissus d'ameublement. Les couleurs peuvent déteindre en raison de la nature de la teinture indigo du denim.,;
Kontakt mit hellen Stoffen, Leder und Polstermöbeln vermeiden. Aufgrund der Indigofärbung kann sich die Farbe übertragen,;
Evitar el contacto con tejidos de colores claros, con cuero y con tapicerías. El tinte índigo de los vaqueros podría transferirse a dichas superficies.,;
Evitare il contatto con capi dai colori delicati, pelli e tappezzerie. Si potrebbe verificare una perdita del colore blu intenso del tessuto di jeans., 
']
```

EDIT:
Here is the entire standalone working function:

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/Translation_Table_Edit.xlsx'
translationFile = pd.read_excel(excel_file, encoding='utf-8')


compList = ['Avoid contact with light-coloured fabrics, leather and upholstery. Colour may transfer due to the nature of indigo-dyed denim.', 'Do not soak']
newComp = []

def myFunction():
    global newComp
    for i in range(len(compList)):
        newComp.append(translationFile.loc[translationFile['English'] == compList[i]].to_string(index=False, header=False))
        newComp = [i.replace('  ', ';') for i in newComp]
myFunction()
strippedComp = [item.lstrip() for item in newComp]
print(strippedComp)
```

This outputs following:

```
['Avoid contact with light-coloured fabrics, lea...;�viter le contact avec les tissus clairs, le c...;Kontakt mit hellen Stoffen, Leder und Polsterm...;Vermijd contact met lichtgekleurde stoffen, le...;Evitar el contacto con tejidos de colores clar...;Evitare il contatto con capi dai colori delica...', 'Do not soak;Ne pas laisser tremper;Nicht einweichen;Niet weken;No dejar en remojo;Non lasciare in ammollo']
```

Comment: @Datanovice Pleases see edited post. I initially thought what you said... that i have ';' somewhere in the cells. its not the case. I've made new entry in my data with this exact sentence cut in half - in all languages.English and French came through perfect. the last three again got cut as the sentences are a lot longer in these languages.

Comment: can you show input too ? what you get when you do `pd.read_excel()`

Comment: @Datanovice please see edit for stand alone function

Comment: do you see `translationFile ` post 5 rows from that  if you are able, if not create a demo sample, the lack of answers is due to not having a [mcve]

Comment: You are right. You can download the file from this link: https://github.com/babis95/TranslationSoftware/tree/master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues lies with calling `to_string` on a dataframe. Instead, first extract the values into an array (`df_sub.iloc[0].values`), and then join the elements of that list (`';'.join(...)`).

This should do the trick:

```
def myFunction():
    global newComp
    for i in range(len(compList)):
        df_sub = translationFile.loc[translationFile['English'] == compList[i]]
        if df_sub.shape[0] > 0:
            newComp.append(';'.join(df_sub.iloc[0].values))
```

**EDIT**: suggested code improvements

In addition, (in my opinion) your code could be improved by the following (using pandas functionality instead of looping, adherence to naming convention in pep8, avoiding use of global variables):

```
import pandas as pd

df_translations = pd.read_excel('./Translation_Table_Edit.xlsx', encoding='utf-8')
to_translate = ['Avoid contact with light-coloured fabrics, leather and upholstery. Colour may transfer due to the nature of indigo-dyed denim.',
            'Do not soak']

def get_translations(df_translations, to_translate, language='English'):
    """Looks up translatios for all items in to_translate.
    Returns a list with semi-colon separated translations. None if no translations found."""

    df_sub = df_translations[df_translations[language].isin(to_translate)].copy()  # filter translations
    df_sub = df_sub.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())  # strip each cell

    # format and combine translations into a list
    ret = []
    for translation in df_sub.values:
        ret.append(';'.join(translation))

    return ret

translations = get_translations(df_translations, to_translate)
```